# How to set theme in fragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app in which i have a MainActivity which contains a fragment that extends BottomSheetDialogFragment. What I want to set fragment theme but it remains same.Pls help

Code for fragment that extends BottomSheetDialogFragment:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:theme="@style/CoffeeDialog">

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_Camera"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/amazon"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/textColor"
    app:civ_border_width="5dp"
    app:civ_fill_color="@color/colorPrimary" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/notification_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp">

</FrameLayout>
```

here i am using android:theme="@style/CoffeeDialog" but it's not working.

Code for theme:-

```
  <style name="CoffeeDialog" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.3</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

Note:- I only want to change fragment theme, not MainActivity.

Answer (score 30):

Try below-given code

```
 public class CustomDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

      @Override
      public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CoffeeDialog);
      }

      ...
    }
```

`CoffeeDialog` will be the theme added to your `styles.xml`

Comment: This works like a charm. However is there a way to include in the app theme?

Answer (score 8):

In your fragment add your theme with the `getTheme` method
like this:

```
override fun getTheme(): Int {
        return R.style.CustomBottomSheetDialog
    }
```